# str.replace command not working in python

Tags: python, replace

I have a line below in my file:

```
line = 'abc01abc'
```

I tried replacing `01` in this line with `1`

```
line = str.replace(line , '01' , '1')
```

but its not replacing .

Please help

Comment: When I copy and paste those two lines of code, then `print(line)`, I get `abc1abc`. Is that not what you expected?

Comment: More generally, part of a [mcve] is including the output you expected, what you did to see it, and what you got instead.

Comment: By the way, although calling methods this is _correct_, it's weird and non-idiomatic. The normal way is to call them on instances, not the type: `line = line.replace('01', '1')`. But this does the exact same thing, so it's not going to fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Both:

```
>>> line = 'abc01abc'
>>> line = line.replace('01' , '1')
>>> line
'abc1abc'
>>> line = 'abc01abc'
>>> line = str.replace(line, '01' , '1')
>>> line
'abc1abc'
```

work so your problem does not reside in any of the code you have shown.

Answer (score 0):

This is an *assumption*. You may have assigned something to `str` somewhere before this line in your program. If so, you may delete `str` to use the in-built `str` features.

Try:

```
str ="something"
line = "abc01abc"
del str
line = str.replace(line , '01' , '1')
print(line)
# abc1abc
```

Comment: I am assigning like this
old = "01"
new = "1"
line = str.replace (line , "old" , "new")

Comment: @Chinnu remove all quotes `"` within brackets and try